# Way of passing a var from jquery function through submit form

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I found this code snippet on the web and its precisely what i needed as a beginner to learn from using jquery. My question though is, how would i be able to transfer/pass the value of `counter` that was used in the jquery script part of the html head tag.

When i said about transfer i mean when i click the submit button, assuming i have a form and sent it to my CI_controller.

Other than asking you guys from any function to do this, i have thought of a way myself. I am planning to make a hidden textbox where everytime add or remove textbox i will put the value of counter inside that textbox so when i click the submit button ill know how many textbox was dynamically added. Although, im still new, so i dont know the syntax of doing this.

here's the snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

    var msg = '';
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }
          alert(msg);
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the form input value using jQuery like so:

```
$('form input#field-id').val(yourData); // where yourData is JavaScript variable containing the data/information
```

Given that you have a form which looks like something like:

```
<form action='/save-data' method='post'>
    <input type="text" id="field-id" name="data-name" />

    <input type="text" id="other-field" name="other-data-name" />
</form>
```

EDIT: on the client side you can do $('form textarea').size() which will return the number of textareas inside that particular form.

On the server side you can just loop through $_POST to find out how many textboxes you have like so:

```
$boxcount = 0;
foreach ( $_POST as $name => $value ) {
    if ( strpos($name, "textbox") == 0 ) {
        $boxcount += 1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if i understood your answer, but to explain my question.

sample, i have dynamically added 4 textboxes, with names textbox1 to textbox4. since its dynamic i have no way of telling how many textbox i have on my controller. So in order for me to know how many textbox so i can get all the values with $_POST i need the var count which dictates on the name of the textboxes while adding (name="textbox"+ count)

Comment: Could you explain to me the line of code for strpos($name,"textbox")

does it work like a LIKE query in which it searched for any input with name containing "textbox"